# How do I remove DEC 31 from a date field?

Tags: 7, datetime

I have an event page on a member's portal. I have added a new Date field to the Event Content type and I am leaving the old date field in to show previous events as they are in that table. I'd like to have the new events' dates show up in the same format at the existing Date field.

The problem I have is that DEC 31 comes up after I create a new event. The new Date field is working fine in that it only shows upcoming events on the landing page but when you click on the events tab the DEC 31 comes up on all Dates that are associated with the new Date field.

I looked into the template.php file to try to modify the code to allow the new Date field to show like the existing Date field.

```
case 'events' :
  if ($vars['view_mode'] == 'teaser') {
    hide($vars['content']['field_event_city']);
    hide($vars['content']['field_event_country']);
    hide($vars['content']['field_event_date']);
    hide($vars['content']['field_upcoming_date']);

    $city = !empty($vars['content']['field_event_city'][0]['#markup']) ? sprintf('%s, ', $vars['content']['field_event_city'][0]['#markup']) : '';

    $country = (isset($vars['content']['field_event_country'][0]['#markup'])?$vars['content']['field_event_country'][0]['#markup']:'');

    $vars['location'] = html_entity_decode($city . $country);
  }

  if (!empty($vars['content']['field_event_speakers'])) {
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($vars['field_event_speakers'] as $speaker) {
      $vars['content']['field_event_speakers'][$i]['#avatar_uri'] = AIUser::get($speaker['value'])->get_picture_uri();
      $vars['content']['field_event_speakers'][$i]['#uid'] = $speaker['value'];

      $i++;
    }
  }

  $vars['start_date'] = (isset($vars['node']->field_event_date['und'][0]['value'])?$vars['node']->field_event_date['und'][0]['value']:NULL);
  $vars['end_date'] = (isset($vars['node']->field_event_date['und'][1]['value'])?$vars['node']->field_event_date['und'][1]['value']:NULL);
  break;
```

The field_event_date is the current date field. So I want to add the new date field along with this one and have it print out the same format.

The reason I added a new Date field is because the current Date field is an integer field. I needed to add a Date Time Unix field so that I can allow it to be greater than now.

I checked around the Redaction module but I am unable to find anything on how to get this done.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow what the question is? Are you saying that the new date field misrenders all dates?

Comment: Yes it does. It works fine on the landing page but when you click on the events tab to look at the history of events it shows up as DEC 31